# How to upgrade OpenSSL from 1.0.2g to 1.1.0g in Ubuntu and let python recognize the new OpenSSL

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I have Ubuntu 16.04. It has OpenSSL 1.0.2g. I need to use OpenSSL 1.1.0g. I did:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

But OpenSSL in my Ubuntu machine did not get updated. How can I update it?

I use python socket, ssl modules to make TLS connection in port 443. Will python automatically recognizes OpenSSL 1.1.0g if I updated the old OpenSSL 1.0.2g to OpenSSL 1.1.0g?

The reason for upgrading OpenSSL is I need to run python program ssl socket but I need the program to use OpenSSL 1.1.0g. How to ensure that?